# Weight or impact of variable in correlation

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, methodology

Consider I've have two curves (catgeory1,category2) that are strongly negatively correlated( -0.88). for 1, I've few sub-category (o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z). I want to know the weight of each one in this correlation. I don't know if my question is clear, in other words, I want to establish causality, why these two catgeory are strongly negatively correlated, and knowing the impact of these sub-categories in this correlation.

is there any simple function or method for this ? I would be very greteful if semone could help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example to illustrate a few things. Say you find No. of people wearing shades in a city(series/curve-1) and No of people in that city wearing high boots(series/curve-2).Let's go with the assumption that  there should be a strong negative correlation. Days when rainfall is high, no. of people wearing shades will go down while no. of people boots will go up(to protect feet against cold water). Though there is relation between shades and boots sales, none of them cause the other. Hence the classic - 'correlation does not imply causation'.

Moving on, say we have 5 types of shades(Wayfarer, Aviator etc.). One of these types could be really annoying to wear when it rains hence show max -ve correlation. To find which shades has max -ve corr, you need to find corr between that type sales and boots' sales.

Can further help you if you provide structure of the data set etc.